# Will Android play store crash reports show output from android.util.Log?

Tags: android, google-play-developer-api

I have an app that is crashing on certain phones, and I am able to see the stack trace of the error in Google Developer Console. However, it is not very helpful and it would be much more beneficial to be able to figure out where in my app this crash is occurring. I was thinking about putting "Log.d()" somewhere in order to identify the origin of the crash, but I am not sure if output from Log.d() will appear in the stack trace of a crash report on Google Developer Console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple tools available that you can rely on that. From one hand you could use Firebase Crash tool, which I highly recommend since it's Google's and to the other hand you could use Twitter's Crashlytics. 
Both will do the job.

[Firebase](https://firebase.google.com)
[Crashlytics](https://try.crashlytics.com)